# Unable to add content to an untagged PDF document

Tags: java, itext

I created a stamper based on examples in the iText In Action book (section 6.3 Adding Content with a Stamper). All my example pdf files stamped properly. When trying it with actual production-type documents, it won't stamp. No error - just no stamp. Difference I found (which may be significant) is that the test documents were tagged pdf's, the production files are untagged.

Am I at a show-stopper here?

Comment: I bet that the stamping process works, but that the coordinate system of the production-type documents is not what you expect it to be. In that case, you're adding the content outside the visible area of the page.

Comment: Please check if your question isn't a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522965/how-to-add-a-watermark-to-a-pdf-file In any case: it isn't impossible to stamp extra text on a Tagged PDF document (if you do it correctly).

Comment: Read more about preserving the Tagged PDF status in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500586/itext-page-number-in-header-within-pdf-a When we talk about "Level A" in the context of PDF/A, we talk about a PDF/A document that is also a Tagged PDF.

Comment: @Larry what about providing sample code and PDF to illustrate your issue.