# PdfContentByte not adding text Tagget Structure

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, tagged-pdf

I am trying to add text using ItextSharp Version 5.5.6.0 
On one of the segments we are using PdfContentByte to write the text 
Assume that pdfPageContents is the instance of PdfContentByte with the content byte

```
        pdfPageContents.SaveState();
        pdfPageContents.BeginText();
        pdfPageContents.SetFontAndSize(bf, fontSize);
        pdfPageContents.SetColorFill(color);
        pdfPageContents.ShowTextAligned(Aling, text, xy.x, xy.y, rotation);
        pdfPageContents.EndText();
```

I have also try

```
        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(pdfPageContents);
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(50, 500, 500, 50);
        ct.SetText(new Phrase(1,new Chunk(text)));
        ct.Go();
```

But in both cases the text gets added but is not include in the tagged structure of the document.

[image]

but my Tagged structure does not include that image
First 2 items are been added in world and they have the tagged structure

[image]

There are only 4 tags 1 for the first text
2 for spaces and 1 for the image, the tagged structure is the same as before adding the "Hello Sir"

Is there any setting that i am missing or is there a work around?

Comment: When you take control (e.g. by using `PdfContentByte`), you are responsible to take care of the tagging yourself. See for instance how the methods `beginMarkedContentSequence()` and `endMarkedCOntentSequence()` are used in my answer to the question [iText page number in header within PDF/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500586/itext-page-number-in-header-within-pdf-a). Automatic tagging is only done when you use high-level objects. When you use absolute positioning, you need to add the tags yourself through code.

Comment: I am currently adding it using PdfStamper and creating the with FileStream passing the byte array. by changing my PdfContentByte to use beginMarkedContentSequence and the ARTIFACT property it does not look to be adding the tag, can you please provide and example, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please contact customer support at iText Software. If you're not a customer, you probably won't get an answer as you're using functionality that is commercially interesting.

Comment: Wait support is only available to the commercial licencing, does this means that AGPL do not have this functionality?  or are we force to pay for licencing now even when what we are doing are experiments that as required are disclose with the rest of the world under the same AGPL requirements.

Comment: You are asking for time and resources. Time and resources are not free. That's obvious, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, that is why i am asking on stackoverflow :D, just to make sure i am still using AGPL rigth, Thanks Bruno for your time, BTW awesome book on the main product