# Resolve accessibility issues with tables using iText java api

Tags: java, itext, accessibility

How to create tables using iText which are as per accessibility guidelines?

I have certain tables created using iText java API and I have the following accessibility issues to address in them.

```
TR must be a child of Table, THead, TBody, or TFoot
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue when using iText or know how to address this issue?

UPDATE:

I am sharing the code I used for this issue.

```
headerTable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, headerX, headerY, writer.getDirectContent());
```

writing table content to given x,y position using **iText 5.5.10**

Comment: Your question can't be answered because you're not showing us how you are creating your PDF (and how you're creating a row without a table, which is really strange). Also: you're not even telling us whether you're using iText 5 (the old version that has some support or PDF/UA) or the new iText 7 (the version that was written with PDF/UA in mind).

Comment: @Bruno Strictly interpreting the tags, the OP uses iText 5, after all he uses [tag:itext] and not [tag:itext7]. Considering it's his first question, though, one admittedly cannot be sure...

Comment: @Bruno I have updated my question with the code fragment I had used.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I am assuming that you are adding a header. As a header is not part of the actual content, you are making a mistake tagging the table as a real table. Things like running headers should be tagged as Artifacts because they aren't part of the real content (you don't want every header to be read out load, do you; that would go against the PDF/UA standard).

See for instance [iText page number in header within PDF/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500586/itext-page-number-in-header-within-pdf-a) where we add a header like this:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
canvas.beginMarkedContentSequence(PdfName.ARTIFACT);
table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 36, 30, canvas);
canvas.endMarkedContentSequence();
```

Note that this answer is only valid if my assumption that you're adding the table as a header is correct.